Unable to View Git Changes/Differences on IntelliJ
I have recently upgraded Git from version 2.37.1 to version 2.45.1. After the upgrade, I could not carry out git "compare version" successfully. As the IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) was not bringing up any differences between selected branches. Please see below image:


A self-answered question must still be a separate, high quality question ([ask]) and answer ([answer]).

Update the version as follows:

